# draw buffered image ontop of another buffered image

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, graphics2d

my goal is to draw some bufferedimage onto another. then all this stuff draw onto some other bufferedimage and so on. And finally draw this on top of a panel. 
For now i'm trying to draw bufferedimage onto panel and nothing works. My bufferedimage looks completely white:

```
public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("asdf");
        final JPanel panel = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                somepaint(panel);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void somepaint(JPanel panel) {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(200,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        image.getGraphics().setColor(Color.red);
        image.getGraphics().fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) panel.getGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(Color.magenta);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        graphics.drawImage(image, null, 0, 0); // draws white square instead of red one
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: *"And finally draw this on top of a panel."* Why not just add it to an `ImageIcon`, add that to a `JLabel`, and add the label to the panel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Re:

```
private static void somepaint(JPanel panel) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(200,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    image.getGraphics().setColor(Color.red);
    image.getGraphics().fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) panel.getGraphics();
```

This is not how you draw inside of a JPanel or JComponent.

Don't call `getGraphics()` on a component as the Graphics object returned will be short-lived, and anything drawn with it will not persist. Instead do your JPanel's drawing inside of its `paintComponent(Graphics G)` method override. You will need to create a class that extends JPanel in order to override `paintComponent(...)`.

Most importantly, to see how to do Swing graphics correctly, don't guess. You'll want to read the [Swing Graphics Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) first as it will require you to toss out some incorrect assumptions (I know that this is what I had to do to get it right).

Answer (score 3):

You need to rectify your parameters in the `drawImage()` call. Change this:

```
graphics.drawImage(image, null, 0, 0);
```

to

```
graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0,null);
```

Check the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) for more details.